# Securing aspx page method or webservices method calls through jQuery

Tags: asp.net, security, session-cookies

How do I secure my aspx page method or webservices method call through jQuery?

I found some answers on Google but I'm still not sure about the details.

#### What I found:

I would secure it by making sure the request is from the same session that the page 
is served in.

> You can do this by issuing a signed cookie when you return the page
>   that  contains that javascript that is going to callback into your web
>   service.  When your page makes the ajax call, it will include this
>   signed cookie,  which you can validate within your web method before
>   returning any results.
>
> To prevent cookie spoofing, store a unique tokenID in your session and
>   make  that tokenID part of your cookie. If the tokenID's do not match,
>   don't process  the web method (just return an error).

1. How do I make sure that request is from the same session?
2. How do I include a signed cookie when page makes the ajax call?
3. What is a signed cookie?